# How to get RSS use JavaScript, jQuery, Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json, rss

I have an RSS page is `http://uat.specialty.mims.com/rss-feed/RSS-SG.xml`. I would like to get data from that RSS and convert to JSON.

I tried with [Google Feed API](https://developers.google.com/feed/v1/devguide), but `that API is no longer available`.

Please help me how to get RSS above and convert to JSON use basic JavaScript, JS library, Angular.

Comment: If using 3rd party? is that possible?

Comment: Yes, Please suggest me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use YQL from Yahoo.

https://jsfiddle.net/iamjpg/bg4gq5hj/

***Open your console to see the response in JSON.***

```
$.getJSON('https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20xml%20where%20url%3D%27http%3A%2F%2Fuat.specialty.mims.com%2Frss-feed%2FRSS-SG.xml%27&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys', function(res) {
    console.log(res)
})
```

Reference to YQL:

https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/